# Split a long string into smaller strings based on delimiter and max length?

Tags: string, bash, awk, sed

I have long strings in a bash script that I would like to break up into substrings. The delimiters are && or || and also (the difficult part) each substring can be no more than 70 characters.

For ex., a long single string like this:

```
(Dfa_and_Cfa && Second_Up_or_Down && Third_Down_or_Up_or_Positive) || (First_Up_or_Down) && Third_Down_or_Up && Dfa_and_Cfa && Third_Down_or_Up && Fourth_Up_or_Down
```

Broken up into:

```
(Dfa_and_Cfa && Second_Up_or_Down && Third_Down_or_Up_or_Positive) ||
(First_Up_or_Down) && Third_Down_or_Up && Dfa_and_Cfa &&
Third_Down_or_Up && Fourth_Up_or_Down
```

So far I was using awk like this:

- Get the max# of fields

  `max_fields=$(echo $long_string | awk -F'[&][&]|[|][|]' '{ print NF }')`
- Calculate the length of each field
- If length less than 70, print out all fields under length 70
- Keep going for remaining fields

But with awk I loose my && and || symbols. So I ended up printing out:

```
Dfa_and_Cfa Second_Up_or_Down Third_Down_or_Up_or_Positive
```

I don't think this is the right approach anymore. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
longstring="(Dfa_and_Cfa && Second_Up_or_Down && Third_Down_or_Up_or_Positive) || (First_Up_or_Down) && Third_Down_or_Up && Dfa_and_Cfa && Third_Down_or_Up && Fourth_Up_or_Down"

printf "%s" "${longstring}" | sed -e 's/\(&&\)/\1\n/g' -e 's/\(||\)/\1\n/g' |\
 awk -v maxlen=70 '{
   stringlen=length(string);
   if (stringlen == 0 || ((stringlen + length($0)) <= maxlen)) string=string $0
   else { print string; string=$0}}
   END {if (length(string)>0) print string}'

(Dfa_and_Cfa && Second_Up_or_Down && Third_Down_or_Up_or_Positive) ||
 (First_Up_or_Down) && Third_Down_or_Up && Dfa_and_Cfa &&
 Third_Down_or_Up && Fourth_Up_or_Down
```

The first `sed` command uses 2 regex to add new lines after `&&` and `||`.

The `awk` command reads each line (`$0`) and build a `string` which is the concatenation of the lines. If the sum of the lengths of `string` and `$0` exceeds `maxlen` (70) then the current `string` is printed, and the `string` is set to current line.

Comment: works perfectly. Thanks so much for the explanation too!

Answer (score 4):

Why not try using fold?

```
$ str='(Dfa_and_Cfa && Second_Up_or_Down && Third_Down_or_Up_or_Positive) || (First_Up_or_Down) && Third_Down_or_Up && Dfa_and_Cfa && Third_Down_or_Up && Fourth_Up_or_Down'
$ fold -sw70 <<< "$str"
(Dfa_and_Cfa && Second_Up_or_Down && Third_Down_or_Up_or_Positive) || 
(First_Up_or_Down) && Third_Down_or_Up && Dfa_and_Cfa && 
Third_Down_or_Up && Fourth_Up_or_Down
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes, that was my first thought too BUT it'll split the lines at any space whereas the OP seems to want the lines split after a separator, `&&` or `||` (otherwise why mention them and see the expected output which just coincidentally matches the `fold` output) which you can't do with fold unless you pre-and-post process with sed or similar to remove/add the spaces before the separators and even then your counts will be off by the number of separators. Also if there is a symbol that's 70+ characters long then `fold` will split it at 70 characters which is probably undesirable.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton. All great points. I'm probably guilty of simplying the data set by considering only the given use case. Awk is definitely more robust, so you have my vote for it. The -s flag in fold would ensure it only folds on space and not on symbol.

Comment: @jaypalsingh thanks. The `-s` flag is just a suggestion to split the text at spaces **if possible** though. By contrast `fold` considers the specific line width to be absolutely required and so it **WILL** fold at 70 characters and if no space is available then it'll just cut up symbols. Try `echo '12345' | fold -sw3` to get the 2 output lines `123` and `45`.

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah, I see what you are saying. Thanks again for the constructive feedback. You're the best as always!

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for the 4th arg to split():

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    prev = ""
    nf = split($0,f,/\s*(&&|\|\|)\s*/,s)
    for (i=1;i<=nf;i++) {
        curr = f[i] s[i]
        if ( length(prev curr) > 70 ) {
            print prev
        }
        else {
            curr = prev curr
        }
        prev = curr
    }
    print curr
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
(Dfa_and_Cfa && Second_Up_or_Down && Third_Down_or_Up_or_Positive) ||
(First_Up_or_Down) && Third_Down_or_Up && Dfa_and_Cfa &&
Third_Down_or_Up && Fourth_Up_or_Down
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution using awk:

**The code:**

```
echo $long_string | awk -F'[&][&]|[|][|]' '{ for(i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i }' | awk  '{if(length($0)<70) print}'
```

**The explanation:**

I separate the fields by space with:

```
 for(i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i
```

Then I consume the output with the pipe and I print only if the length is less than 70:

```
 | awk  '{if(length($0)<70) print}'
```

I you want to use the remaining fields shorter than 70 you have to add a pipe (|) and put another command